# using rest show details

Tags: php, html, rest, restful-url

using rest want to show the details about the items but there is a bug in the  function code but according to me that is right but there is error in 7th line. i have two code they are as follow
index.php

```html
<?php
header("content-Type:application/json");
include("function.php");
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $price = get_price($name);

    if(empty($price))
        deliver_response(200,"book not found",NULL);
    else
        deliver_response(200,"book found",price);
}
else{
    deliver_response(400,"invalid",NULL);
}

function deliver_response($status,$status_message,$data)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 $status $status_message");

    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;

    $json_response=json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;


}
?>
```

the function code

```html
<?php
function get_price($find)
{
    $books = array(
        "java" => 300,
        "c"    => 250,
        "php"  => 350);
    for($books as $book => $price) {

        if($books == $find) {
            return $price;
            break;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a foreach loop instead of a for loop and $book instead of $books in your if statement.

```
foreach ( $books AS $book => $price ) {
    if ( $book == $find ) {
        return $price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change here, change `books` to `book`

```
 if($book==$find)
             {
             return $price;
             break;
             }
```

Also change `foreach` instead of `for` its `foreach` syntax check this manual : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `foreach` loop, not a `for` loop. And you don't need break, as it will never reach it. Also, `books` inside the loop need to be `book`, or else you're comparing to the array, not the key.

```
    foreach($books as $book => $price) {
        if($book == $find) {
            return $price;
        }
    }
```